# QGIS 3 field calculator- hide name of one field (column/attribute)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis2web

My code:

```
CASE 
WHEN length("Straße/Nr.")>0 THEN ( ( 'Name: '+ "Name" ) +'<br>'+  ( 'Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr." ) +'<br>'+ ('Religion: ' + "Religion" ) +'<br>'+ (  'URL: '+  "URL" ) ) 
WHEN length("Name")>0 THEN( ( 'Name: '+ "Name" )  +'<br>'+ ('Religion: ' + "Religion" ) +'<br>'+ (  'URL: '+  "URL" ) ) 
WHEN length("Religion")>0 THEN(  ('Religion: ' + "Religion" ) +'<br>'+ (  'URL: '+  "URL" ) ) 
WHEN length("URL")>0 THEN( (  'URL: '+  "URL" )) 
END
```

Result:

[image]

All is OK, but one problem:
How can I hide "URL: " if there are no content?

I have different results in my popups of qgis2web: Sometimes I have no value for URL or sometimes no value for Religion. All ok. Only the "URL:" is my problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me a bug in your expression. Try with the following:

```
IF( length( "Name") > 0, ( 'Name: ' + "Name") + '<br>', '') +
IF( length( "Straße/Nr.") > 0, ( 'Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr.") + '<br>', '') +
IF( length( "Religion") > 0, ( 'Religion: ' + "Religion") + '<br>', '') +
IF( length( "URL") > 0, ( 'URL: ' + "URL" ) + '<br>', '')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Follow question: I have tried to insert blank characters after the word "name". With this command: IF( length( "Name") > 0, ( 'Name: '+ '         '  + "Name") + '<br>', '') +. In the table it looks like good, but in the popup (qgis2web/leaflet) no reaction, no more additional blank characters. Any idea?
edit: upps, here the comment line shows the code not correct my blank characters - same problem here.....hmm. blank characters are there: 'Name: '+ ' HERE'  + "Name"....

Comment: You are welcome! It is a property of HTML, compresses all spaces between words in just one space. `IF( length("Name")>0, ( 'Name: '+ '&nbsp;' +"Name" )` would work.

Comment: Fantastic!! This I need.